# fastcgi_pass is calling but index.html is ignored in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I have the following business logic: index.html is loaded from 
root url (location /) and fastcgi is called by /fcgi url (location /fcgi) and 
also I send url parameters to fastcgi and parse there. 
In nginx.conf I have got 2 separate locations: location / and location /fcgi. 
What is happening: when I access root url localhost:9001/ index.html is not 
loaded from "location /" but calling "location /fcgi" and doing fastcgi_pass 
with root url. This breaks my fastcgi program since no parameter is passing 
and it is showing Debug error (testing on Windows). Finally server shows page error 
instead of showing simply index.html. Why root match localhost:9001/ calling "location /fcgi" but not "location /" ? How to make nginx to load index.html with url localhost:9001/ 
but not calling /fcgi at the same time ?

```
Below is my nginx.conf.

server {
listen       9001;
server_name  localhost;
root   E:/data/;

location / { 
index  index.html;
}

location /fcgi {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
}

}
```

Comment: You mention port 9000, but in your config server listen to 9001

Comment: sorry typing, edited to 9001, problem still existing

Comment: I see no reason for nginx to behave like that. Have you restarted nginx? Don't you have another server block listening to 9001?

Comment: I'm restarting every time after changing nginx.conf. But location /fcgi is calling every time I access just a root url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of this issue which is simple: 
using extra slash at the end in location "/fcgi/" instead of "/fcgi". 
In that case nginx can split calls, otherwise nginx  is dealing with locations "/" and "/fcgi" as with one location. Will appreciate if someone can explain why it is working like that.